# How do you debug facebook connect apps and xfbml parsing using the javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, debugging, facebook, sdk

I'm failing making the Facebook javascript SDK work to parse xfbml. I'd like to debug but I can't see anything in the FB documentation about it.

I explorered the following solutions, and combinations of them:

- Creating a div for the log:

  ```
  <div id="log-container">
      <div id="log"></div>
  </div>
  ```
- Setting the verbosity level:

  ```
   FB.init({
   appId  : 'app_id',
   status : true, 
   cookie : true, 
   xfbml  : true,
   level  : "debug"
   });
  ```
- includes the debug sdk

  ```
  <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.debug.js"></script>
  ```

Can't get anything to work.

Comment: What happens when you try?  Do you use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools?  Are you putting the `FB.init` within a Load event, or having it interpreted immediately?

Comment: Thanks for you help dorkitude. I do use Chrome Developper Tools and I set FB.init in the $() jquery function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Facebook provide a way to load debug JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364982/does-facebook-provide-a-way-to-load-debug-js)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the debug is supported anymore for FB.init() in the SDK.  This question may be irrelevant now.