# Connect Facebook Application via JavaScript: FacebookAPI.debug.js session parameter not found

Tags: facebook, javascript

I'm trying to embed a Facebook-Application via the library `FacebookAPI.debug.js`.
This can ends in an almost indefinite reloading of the page. The reason for reloading is the call to requireLogin().
In this method (in the called methode: `_verifyLogin$1=`) a session parameter `"session"` is expected, but there is only a parameter `fb_sig_session_key`.

Question:

- Is FacebookAPI.debug.js outdated by a new Facebook API?
- Is the bug http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=7780 related?
- What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely an outdated version, a debug version is available [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

> In order to help with debugging, we
>   provide a debug version of the SDK
>   (available for the en_US locale only):

```
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.debug.js
```

**EDIT:**
Checking both versions of the JS library they seems identical to me, so the the best to actually debug the library is by using the [JavaScript Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console).
[image]

Comment: How has this debug version core.debug.js to be included? Instead of all.js or before or after all.js?

Comment: Where does the debug output go to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713882/how-do-you-debug-facebook-connect-apps-and-xfbml-parsing-using-the-javascript-sdk