# Facebook JS SDK Documentation

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm playing with the [Facebook JS SDK console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/) and I'm looking for the documentation on some of these flags.  The [official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and [FB.init](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/) offers some insight, but not everything.

```
{
 "appid": "184484190795",
 "level": "debug",
 "locale": "en_US",
 "server": "",
 "trace": 0,
 "version": "mu",
 "module": "all",
 "status": 1,
 "autoRun": true,
 "orange": false,
 "oauth": 1,
 "frictionlessRequests": 1,
 "logging": 1,
 "xfbml": 1,
 "channelUrl": 1,
 "authResponse": 1,
 "hideFlashCallback": 1,
 "cookie": 1    
}
```

I'm going to comment on each one, please feel free to correct me:

- **locale**

  - Change the locale of the SDK to match the locale of your site, change en_US to a supported locale code when loading the SDK. [Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#hide_flash_callback)
- **server**

  - Not sure about this one.  Deprecated?
- **trace**

  - Not sure about this one.  Deprecated?
- **version**

  - Not sure about this one.  Deprecated?
- **module**

  - Not sure about this one.  Deprecated?
- **status**

  - Checks user's login status on load. Set to true by default.
- **autoRun**

  - Not sure about this one.  Deprecated?
- **orange**

  - Not sure about this one.  Deprecated?
- **frictionlessRequests**

  - Enables sharing with minimal user action.  See more [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#frictionless_requests)
- **logging**

  - Outputs messages to the console.  I'm guessing that error levels were supported at one time, but no longer.  Set to true by default.
- **level**

  - Error levels.  I've read that this is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735853/331813)
- **xfbml**

  - Allows parsing of xfbml tags.  Stuff like `<fb:login-button>`  I believe this is deprecated in favour of divs with classes.  e.g `<div class="fb-login-button">`
- **channelUrl**

  - Allows cross domain communication.  Think CORS. Specify a url to allow.  More info [here](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.init)
- **hideFlashCallback**

  - Allows you to provide a custom hide and display function.  More info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#hide_flash_callback)
- **cookie**

  - Enables cookie support.  I'm guessing this is needed for oauth.  False by default.